# Python: NLTK and Spacy, don't get same result when tokenize sentence in French

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I want to split french text into sentences.

With [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize.html#sent_tokenize), I use the sentence tokenizer directly as follows:

```
import nltk.data
tokenizer = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/french.pickle')
tokens = tokenizer.tokenize("Film culte, classique parmi les classiques.Enfin un conte de Noël bien adapté aux tout-petits sans les prendre pour des attardés.")
for sentence in tokens:
    print(sentence)
```

But I got just one sentence:

> Film culte, classique parmi les classiques.Enfin un conte de Noël bien
> adapté aux tout-petits sans les prendre pour des attardés.

With [Spacy](https://spacy.io/models/fr), I do this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")
doc = nlp("Film culte, classique parmi les classiques.Enfin un conte de Noël bien adapté aux tout-petits sans les prendre pour des attardés.")
for sentence in doc.sents:
    print(sentence.text)
```

I have both sentences right. Which is correct.

> Film culte, classique parmi les classiques.

> Enfin un conte de Noël bien adapté aux tout-petits sans les prendre pour des attardés.

Why it's not good with NLTK?

Answer (score 0):

For the moment, I applied this workaround with the use of this regular expression:

> (?<=[.!?])(?=[^\s])

- `(?<=[.!?])` positive lookbehind that looks for . ! ?
- `(?=[^\s])` positive lookahead that matches anything that isn't a space

So this will match positions just after the comma or the space like `phrase.Ceci` or `texte?Cela` but not `mot. Le` and replace with a single space ( )

**Python code:**

```
texte="Film culte, classique parmi les classiques.Enfin un conte de Noël bien adapté aux tout-petits sans les prendre pour des attardés. Un espace après le point?Sans espace après le point d'interrogation."
texte = re.sub(r'(?<=[.!?])(?=[^\s])', r' ', texte)
print(texte)
```

**Output:**

> Film culte, classique parmi les classiques. Enfin un conte de Noël
> bien adapté aux tout-petits sans les prendre pour des attardés. Un
> espace après le point? Sans espace après le point d'interrogation.